# jQuery datepicker - default date as selected date when using dateFormat

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have a jquery datepicker which selects week number and a date range based on what date is picked.

```
$("input").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        $(this).val("Week Number " + $.datepicker.iso8601Week(new Date(dateText)) + " • " + $.datepicker.formatDate('d M', new Date(dateText)) + " - " + $.datepicker.formatDate('d M yy', new Date(new Date(dateText).getTime() + 6*24*60*60*1000)));
    }
});
```

The trouble is, by formatting the date using this method, it prevents the datepicker from defaulting to the selected date when you click the input again. It defaults to the current date.

I have to use this method due to some of the other code I am using (I've avoided showing this because it's long and not relevant to this problem).

Any ideas how I can get it to default to the previously selected date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following line to the function that will be called for the `onSelect` event

```
$.datepicker.setDefaults({"defaultDate":dateText});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/ELXGP/5/

Answer (score 1):

You can always set the date "by hand" calling the:

```
.datepicker("setDate", defaultDate);
```

method.
But prior to that take a look at the [wast number of properties](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/) you can set to the datepicker, maybe one of the will solve your problem.

Comment: This doesn't work, it still defaults back to today after you select something

Answer (score 1):

You can apply date-picker to some other textfield and whenever date is selected you can modify your textfield content.

Comment: This would work, but i'd rather not have unnecessary text fields all over my code. If there's another way around this it would be preferable.